# Saving an entity with a nested object with Crud repo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, crud

How to save a entity with another entity nested to it ?

Repo

```
public interface ReservationRepository extends JpaRepository<Reservation, Integer> {
    Optional<Reservation> findReservationBySection_SectionId(int id);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class ReservationService {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    @Autowired
    private ReservationRepository reservationRepository;
    @Autowired
    private SectionRepository sectionRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public Reservation addReservation(Reservation reservation) {
        Reservation newReservation = new Reservation();
        newReservation.setCount(reservation.getCount());
        newReservation.setCustom_section_name(reservation.getCustom_section_name());
        newReservation.setFrom_time(reservation.getFrom_time());
        newReservation.setTo_time(reservation.getTo_time());
        newReservation.setSection(sectionRepository.getOne(reservation.getSection().getSectionId()));
        newReservation.setUser(userRepository.getOne(reservation.getUser().getUserId()));
        logger.info(newReservation.toString());
        return reservationRepository.save(newReservation);
    }

}
```

User entity

```
User
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "expiration_date")
    private Timestamp expirationDate;
```

Section Entity

```
Section
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "section_id")
    private int sectionId;

    @Column(name = "section_name")
    private String sectionName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="room_id")
    private Section roomId;
```

Reservation Entity

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "reservation_id")
    private int reservationId;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("section_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "section_id")
    private Section section;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("user_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "count")
    private int count;

    @Column(name = "custom_section_name")
    private String custom_section_name;

    @Column(name = "from_time")
    private Timestamp from_time;


    @Column(name = "to_time", unique = true)
    private Timestamp to_time;
```

Expected result:

Want to save a Reservation with section and user in database. Like this:
[image: Expected result]

Actual result:

Reservation created but with missing section_id and user_id
[image: Actual result]

SQL database table has section_id and user_id to not null because of primary keys in their tables.
Will provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Reservation owns the relationship with Section, you need to add Cascade to the relationship. When you persist Reservation, Hibernate will intercept the fact that you want to also persist a Section and attach its corresponding reference to the Reservation entity.

You can add

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "section_id")
    private Section section;
```

You can modify the Cascade type as you want ( eg: if you do not want to cascade the delete operation )

Here is a good article:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

Comment: Hi thank you for taking the time to answer. This, however didnt solve the problem but I learned that cascading with the reservation is a smart thing. For clearification: I get from the endpoint a Reservation object that I want to save in the database but this is not allowed because im having a section and user object in the data sendt to the reservation. Therefor I trying to figure out who I can save a reservation with a refrence to a section and a user.

Comment: There is one more trick that you can try.

Add `nullable = false` at the @JoinColumn for Section and User entities:

`@JoinColumn(name = "section_id", nullable = false)`

`@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)`

Comment: Still getting the " Field 'section_id' doesn't have a default value" as a problem. Mabye it has something to do with this? Its hard to figure out but it seems like the entity refrence does not get saved with the new Reservation.

Comment: Can you please also remove the `@MapsId`, it has no sense to be there.

Comment: Seems like that fixed it. Thank you!